# jQuery: intercept form submit and build data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with some custom values and I want to intercept it's submission and build myself the data that is passed to the backend.

I've searched and I can intercep the submit by doing:

```
$("#search-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    form.submit();
});
```

Before manually submitting, I want to build the data passed to the backend. For example, I would like to build the following data:

```
{
  search: {
    someField1: "someValue1",
    someField2: "someValue2",
    someFields: [
      {
        nestedField1: "value1",
      },
      {
        nestedField2: "value2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To be clear, the original data from the form I want to completely remove, I don't care what's in it.

Comment: Forms are POSTed using url-encoded pairs.  It looks like you want to POST JSON.  Can you confirm what the POST body should look like?

Comment: Try using the [FormData Object API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: So you want to build an object with data that you have predetermined and send that *instead of whatever data the user entered?*

Comment: No, I'll be using the data the user entered, but with another format.

Answer (score 1):

You could intercept the form submit , cancel it and just use a ajax call to send over whatever you like.

```js
var data = {
  search: {
    someField1: "someValue1",
    someField2: "someValue2",
    someFields: [{
        nestedField1: "value1",
      },
      {
        nestedField2: "value2"
      }
    ]
  }
};
$('#test').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $.post(this.action, data);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test" action="http://google.com" method="POST">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` and `return false` are not needed.

Comment: @Mikey I guess in most cases you are right. However the e ent can bubble and if one of the parents listen the preventDefat will not stop the parent handler. Also if one is checking if the event fired the handler return matters. `if(obj.fireEve t(eventName)!==false)`